# Does the speed of light increase when falling?

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light

The Schwarzschild form has a singularity at the Schwarzschild radius. If we write the metric in another form, such as the Lemaître form, the singularity disappears. In the Schwarzschild form the speed of light remains isotropic with respect to the distant observer, but in the Lemaître form the light remains isotropic with respect to the faller falling from infinity. Does this mean that in fact the speed of light falls with the faller and therefore that it accelerates as it falls? Obviously, if the light remains isotropic with respect to the distant observer it will never pass the singularity.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro_time_delay

Comment: Shapiro delay is a two-way trip. On a round trip the light will slow down, but it is anisotropic.